# Convert RGB value to CMYK using an ICC profile? c#

Tags: c#, wpf, rgb, cmyk, color-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# convert RGB value to CMYK using an ICC profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237104/c-sharp-convert-rgb-value-to-cmyk-using-an-icc-profile)

Well.. I've been working on this for some time and discovered many things about this world, but could not perform one conversion. If I use:

> ```
> System.Windows.Media.Color color = Color.FromValues(colorValues,
>             new Uri(@"D:\ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc"));
> ```

Or any other color profile, I get a great result!
But the parameter "colorValues​​" is in CMYK, and the result value is in RGB. =(

I need to pass the values ​​in RGB and the method return me the value in CMYK. Preferably corresponding with the above conversion or some value close.

Some links I found:

- [C# convert RGB value to CMYK using an ICC profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237104/c-sharp-convert-rgb-value-to-cmyk-using-an-icc-profile) (I did exactly what was posted and the result was totally false and incompatible)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorcontext.aspx and
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap(v=vs.85).aspx (I got a number of exceptions.. )
- [Using CMYK colours in WPF/XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827270/using-cmyk-colours-in-wpf-xaml) (..)

Among others, none helped me for various reasons.. (Please not to post the RGB to CMYK formula I would like to use profiles)

Comment: The solution described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237104/c-sharp-convert-rgb-value-to-cmyk-using-an-icc-profile works. Post your code so we can have a look where the problem is.

Comment: Ok, I'll try again .. sometimes I missed some detail in this conversion. Anyway, there would be a simpler way to do what I need?